# Разбить список по 3 элемента и сравнить со словарем

Tags: python

Имеется список.

```
df = data_frame_from_first_table['status_id'].astype(str).values.tolist()
```

На выводе имеется:

```
['2', '7', '0', '2', '7', '0', '3', '2', '7', '1', '7', '0', '3', '1', '7', '3', '1', '7', '1', '7', '0']
```

Есть словарь

```
dict_of_right_transitions = { '1': {'2','7','0'}, '2': {'7','2','3'}, '3': {'7','1','7'}, '4': {'1','3','7'}, '5': {'0','7','1'}, '6': {'7','1','3'} }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разбить список по три элемента и сравнить со словарем? Т. е., чтобы три значения списка сравнивались со значениями словаря.

Comment: Что с чем сравнивать не очень понятно. Покажите на примере ваших данных прямо вот по шагам что и с чем. И что на выходе, собственно, должно быть тоже непонятно.

Comment: у вас значения словаря типа set, т.е. вот это _{'7','1','7'}_ превращается в это {'7','1'}

Comment: @CrazyElf Мне нужно сравнить список значений словаря со списком `df`. Должно проверяться, есть ли значения из разделенного списка в словаре. т.е  

`df = [['2','7','0'], [3', '2', '7']......]` сравнивается со словарем и ищет есть ли совпадения. Если есть, то все хорошо, если нет таких значений в словаре, то выводит комбинацию значений списка, которых нет в словаре

Comment: Вам написали, что у вас словарь, с которым вы сравниваете свой список, задан неверно. у вас словарь наборов (set), а не словарь списков. `'2':{'7', '1', '7'}`  сразу становиться `'2':{'7', '1'}`. Понимаете?

Comment: @Nommad Совпадения должны быть на тех же позициях или в принципе должны быть в значениях словаря нужные комбинации, не важно в каком порядке?

Comment: @strawdog Понял что Вы имеете ввиду. Можно вложить в словарь множество `{1: {2, 3, 4}}` ?

Comment: @CrazyElf Последовательность важна. Если в словаре нет необходимой комбинации последовательности цифр, то она считается ошибочной и выводится

Comment: @strawdog Да, мне ведь нужно сравнить список разбитый по три элемента с чем-то, что будет хранить допустимые комбинации этих элементов. Или это можно сделать не через словарь?

Comment: Вы не понимаете. у вас в словаре значения представлены в виде сетов. почему? set не может хранить одинаковые элементы, понимаете?

Comment: @strawdog, а.... Простите что не понял. Я просто не знаю как еще их можно представить(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поправил словарь на словарь кортежей. Из списка состояний выбираются последовательные не перекрывающиеся тройки и проверяются на принадлежность множеству "правильных" кортежей:

```
transitions = {
    '1': ('2','7','0'),
    '2': ('7','2','3'),
    '3': ('7','1','7'),
    '4': ('1','3','7'),
    '5': ('0','7','1'),
    '6': ('7','1','3')
}

states = ['2', '7', '0', '2', '7', '0', '3', '2', '7', '1', '7', '0', '3', '1', '7', '3', '1', '7', '1', '7', '0']

s = set(transitions.values())
for t in zip(*([iter(states)] * 3)):
    if t not in s:
        print(t)
        break
else:
    print('OK')
```

Comment: а что значит "тройки могут перекрываться?"

Comment: Для вашего примера проверяются тройки `270`, `702`, `027`, `270`, .... Всего проверяется `n - 2` тройки если в списке `n` значений.

Comment: Понял, благодарю

Comment: А такой метод подойдет, если словарь кортежей будет состоять из большего числа позиций? Например не 6, а 250

Comment: Да, подойдёт. Сам словарь не нужен. Вместо него однократно строится множество кортежей. Проверка принадлежности множеству быстрая, почти не зависит от его размера.

Comment: Для скорости можно заменить кортежи на строки или числа.

Comment: Позвольте я напишу как я вижу, а Вы скажите, где я не прав. Мои скиллы весьма скромны.  `s = set(transitions.values())`  # тут строится множество. из словаря кортежей.  `for t in zip(states, states[1:], states[2:]):` # тут список значений преобразуется в список кортежей. И потом проверятся на вхождение в словарь. Все верно? `states[1:], states[2:]` вот это что? 
Каюсь, буду учить матчасть, господа офицеры

Comment: Верно. `states[1:]` - копия списка без первого элемента.

Comment: А для чего тут убирать первый и второй элементы списка `states`? ведь тогда изменятся комбинации в самом списке... разве нет?

Comment: `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `list(zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]))` -> `[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]`.  Сам список не меняется. Это напоминает уборку когда комбайны двигаются по полю уступом.

Comment: Так нужно же не проверка всех комбинаций) я наверно не совсем верно выразился должно быть в `states = [(270),((270),(327)...(170)]`  а не `270, 702, 027, 270, ....`

Comment: Поправил ответ.